# Error While creating a New Node in java

Tags: java

My Node Class:

```
static class Trie{

     int count;
     Trie[] words;

     public Trie(){
         count =-1;
            for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
            words[i] = null;
     }

}
```

My Line of Code For Creating a New Node:

```
if(Root==null)
        Root = new Trie();
```

I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What I have Done Wrong , How to create a new object

Comment: How can you use static keyword with class declaration.Dint it gave you a compilation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized words:

```
words = new Trie[26];
```